# Database Connection Shell

Tags: mysql

I can see someone changed a table value in my database through an unknown place.
Is there a command to check who has connected to mysql database?

Like show ip address and time, etc?

I only have shell access.

Comment: Typically, this is not something that would be on by default. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/

Comment: @ceejayoz that is cool.

Answer (score 0):

`show processlist;` may be what you are looking for. [Here is a link that may help](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql)